# $\Gamma: (0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $\Gamma(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}x^{\alpha-1}dx $

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

$\Gamma: (0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $\Gamma(t)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}x^{t-1}dx $.

I've already got this result, separating the integral

i)Let $t>0$. Show that:

$$\Gamma(t)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}x^{t-1}dx $$ is finite.

$$\Gamma(t)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}x^{t-1}dx=\Gamma(t)=\int_{0}^{1}e^{-x}x^{t-1}dx + \int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-x}x^{t-1}dx$$ .

Now, I would like to get the following result:

ii) $$\Gamma(t)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{n} \big( 1-\frac{x}{n} \big)^n \cdot x^{t-1}dx$$ Using the following results:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \big (1-\frac{x}{n} \big)^n = e^{-x}$$ and $$ \big(1-\frac{x}{n} \big)^n \le  \big(1-\frac{x}{n+1} \big)^{n+1}$$

Then:

$$ \big(1-\frac{x}{n} \big)^n \le  e^{-x}$$ and $$\big(1-\frac{x}{n} \big)^n \rightarrow e^{-x}$$

And I'm not sure if the following steps are correct:

$$ \big(1-\frac{x}{n} \big)^n \cdot x^{t-1}  \le  e^{-x}\cdot x^{t-1}$$

And then apply the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

And the last result:

iii) if $t>1$ $$\Gamma(t)\cdot \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^t}  =\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}} \cdot x^{t-1}dx $$

How could he now get the latest identity?

Try writing both sides of the equality separately. But I didn't get equality

Comment: Yes all points are correct what is your exact question @ibs_bernal?

Comment: I was not sure if the DCT could be applied without problems. But I have already verified that it is. @EDX